Change Audio Output Sink
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 machine, and the audio is currently connected through HDMI. I want to switch it to a USB audio port.
After extensive research, I discovered a method to achieve this by identifying the sink and setting the default sink using the following commands:
pactl list short sinks
pactl set-default-sink <sink_name> or pactl set-default-sink <index>

When I execute the command to change the sink, I do not encounter any errors. However, I do not observe the audio sink being changed.
I also attempted to restart PulseAudio to observe the effects using the 'pulseaudio -k' command. However, after executing this command, all sinks transition to the SUSPENDED state and none of them return to the RUNNING state.
Could someone please assist me with this?
